# 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token o' with angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

It gaves me error when I m trying to call this controller .

```
hiren.controller('hirenz' , function($scope , $http , $location , $routeParams){
    $http.post((rootURL + "music") , {'alpha' : $routeParams.alpha , 'name' : $routeParams.name ,
        'album' : $routeParams.albumname }).success(function(data){
        var parsedJson = JSON.parse(data) ;
        console.log(parsedJson.name);
    });
});
```

Here is the  "data" that i am calling from server

```
{
    "name": [
        "Adhar - Adhar ",
        "Adhar - Adhare Opshori ",
        "Adhar - Aj Neshay "
    ],
    "url": [
        "http://music-com-bd.com/Music/A/Adhar/Adhare Opshori/Adhar - Adhar (music.com.bd).mp3",
        "http://music-com-bd.com/Music/A/Adhar/Adhare Opshori/Adhar - Adhar (music.com.bd).mp3",
        "http://music-com-bd.com/Music/A/Adhar/Adhare Opshori/Adhar - Adhar (music.com.bd).mp3"
    ]
}
```

Comment: 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token o'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are parsing something which is not a string. It might be already in form of JSON object. 
You do not need to parse it.
If you change `var parsedJson = JSON.parse(data) ;` to `var parsedJson = data;` The error will go off.

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs when JSON is not properly formed. Check it with [JSLint](http://jslint.com)